# boost::bind different functions has different return type

Tags: c++, function, boost, bind

I need some kind of callback as `boost::function<void(void)>`, and the callback is assigned by `boost::bind`, code like this:

```
bool func1(int i);
double func2(std::string str);

typedef boost::function<void(void)> callback;

callback cb1 = boost::bind(func1, 1); 
callback cb2 = boost::bind(func2, 1.0f);

cb1();   //what happen here?
cb2();   //how about this?
```

This code can be compiled by vc8, and is all right during running.
my boost is 1.34, is this some kind of bug of boost 1.34
or this kind of code may get the stack crashed.

if so, what should do to solve this, make a wrapper of func1 and func2 is a way, but for our project, is not necessary.

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of Boost?

Comment: You should use a version of Boost that is current enough that it's `function` implementation can handle these.

Comment: if the higher version solved this problem, I may move to the newer one.

Comment: You say "and is all right during running", which means you don't have any problem with the code. So what problem do you actually have with the code?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way this code compiles cleanly. You cannot bind a float as to a function expecting a string argument.  Examples of the error spewage I get if I try and compile your code with boost 1.34.1 & g++ 4.1.2:

```
include/boost-1_34_1/boost/bind.hpp: In member function 'R
boost::_bi::list1<A1>::operator()(boost::_bi::type<R>, F&, A&, long
int) [with R = double, F = double (*)(std::basic_string<char,
std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >), A =
boost::_bi::list0, A1 = boost::_bi::value<float>]':

include/boost-1_34_1/boost/bind/bind_template.hpp:20:   instantiated
from 'typename boost::_bi::result_traits<R, F>::type
boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::operator()() [with R = double, F = double
(*)(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,
std::allocator<char> >), L =
boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<float> >]'

boost-1_34_1/boost/function/function_template.hpp:158:   instantiated
from 'static void
boost::detail::function::void_function_obj_invoker0<FunctionObj,
R>::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&) [with
FunctionObj = boost::_bi::bind_t<double, double
(*)(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,
std::allocator<char> >), boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<float> >
>, R = void]'

include/boost-1_34_1/boost/function/function_template.hpp:787:  
instantiated from 'void boost::function0<R,
Allocator>::assign_to(const Functor&) [with Functor =
boost::_bi::bind_t<double, double (*)(std::basic_string<char,
std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >),
boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<float> > >, R = void, Allocator =
std::allocator<void>]'

include/boost-1_34_1/boost/function/function_template.hpp:624:  
instantiated from 'boost::function0<R, Allocator>::function0(Functor,
typename
boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value,
int>::type) [with Functor = boost::_bi::bind_t<double, double
(*)(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,
std::allocator<char> >), boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<float> >
>, R = void, Allocator = std::allocator<void>]'

include/boost-1_34_1/boost/function/function_template.hpp:886:  
instantiated from 'boost::function<R ()(),
Allocator>::function(Functor, typename
boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value,
int>::type) [with Functor = boost::_bi::bind_t<double, double
(*)(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,
std::allocator<char> >), boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<float> >
>, R = void, Allocator = std::allocator<void>]'

testbind.cpp:18:   instantiated from here
include/boost-1_34_1/boost/bind.hpp:221: error: conversion from
'float' to non-scalar type 'std::basic_string<char,
std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >' requested
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, vc8 can compile the code clearly with no waring and error. after testing the application using the code above, i got a lots of problems, the application has several strange behavior. So i decide to modify the code and never write code like this. thanks.